# What is my age?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, enigmatic-puzzle

> I'm nine, but me is more than three hundred.
>
> You could've been twenty one.
>
> But you are actually around seventeen thousands.
>
> And all of us are more than half a million.

**What is my age?**

Comment: something to do with [Battle_of_Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae) and the 300 Spartans?   All together, perhaps the number of combatants neared half a million?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This puzzle can be understood by

> considering each word as a number written in base 26, with the obvious correspondence of letters to digits ($A\rightarrow1,\dots,Z\rightarrow26$).

*I'm nine, but me is more than three hundred.*

> $I=9$ and $ME=(13*26)+5=343>300$.

*You could've been twenty one.*

> "You" in textspeak is U, and $U=21$.

*But you are actually around seventeen thousands.*

> $YOU=(25*26^2)+(15*26)+21=16900+390+21=17311\approx17000$.

*And all of us are more than half a million.*

> Less sure about this one, but $ALL OF=26^4+(12*26^3)+(12*26^2)+(15*26)+6=456976+210912+8112+390+6=676396>500000$. (Using ALLOFUS would be a more obvious choice, and of course still more than half a million, but *so much* more that the choice of "half a million" in this line would be weird.

*What is my age?*

I guess it's

> either $MY=(13*26)+25=363$ or $AGE=26^2+(7*26)+5=863$.